# How to pan and zoom properly in 2D?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

All I want to do is create a really simple pan and zoom feature in 2D with OpenGL through pyglet. As you can see, the zooming is working perfectly after the first jump:( Then again, the dragging (panning) is also working, but it also jumps (and it jumps a pretty big one)..

Here is my simplified code and a video ([pyglet_test.mp4](http://cl.ly/2x012E0U0Y3x)) that shows how it behaves:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

# Zooming constants
ZOOM_IN_FACTOR = 1.2
ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR = 1/ZOOM_IN_FACTOR



class App(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, width, height, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create GL configuration
        conf = Config(  sample_buffers=1,
                        samples=4,
                        depth_size=16,
                        double_buffer=True )
        # Initialize parent
        super().__init__( width, height, config=conf, *args, **kwargs )

        # Create Group
        self.group = group = pyglet.graphics.Group()
        # Create Batch
        self.batch = batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        # Create QUAD for testing and add it to batch
        batch.add(
            4, GL_QUADS, group,

            ('v2i', ( -50, -50,
                       50, -50,
                       50,  50,
                      -50,  50 )),

            ('c3B', ( 255,   0,   0,
                      255, 255,   0,
                        0, 255,   0,
                        0,   0, 255 ))
        )

        # Initialize OpenGL
        self.init_gl()

        # Initialize camera values
        self.camera_x = 0
        self.camera_y = 0
        self.camera_zoom = 1

    def init_gl(self):
        # Set clear color
        glClearColor(0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 0/255)

        # Set antialiasing
        glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH )
        glEnable( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH )
        glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST )

        # Set alpha blending
        glEnable( GL_BLEND )
        glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA )

        # Set viewport
        glViewport( 0, 0, self.width, self.height )

        # Initialize Projection matrix
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()

        # Set orthographic projection matrix
        glOrtho( 0, self.width, 0, self.height, 1, -1 )

        # Initialize Modelview matrix
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )
        glLoadIdentity()

        # Save the default modelview matrix
        glPushMatrix()

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        # Initialize OpenGL for new dimensions
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height
        self.init_gl()

    def camera_matrix(transformations):

        # Create camera setter function
        def set_camera(self):
            # Take saved matrix off the stack and reset it
            glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )
            glPopMatrix()
            glLoadIdentity()
            # Call wrapped function
            transformations(self)
            # Save default matrix again with camera translation
            glPushMatrix()

        # Return wrapper function
        return set_camera

    @camera_matrix
    def move_camera(self):
        # Move to camera position
        glTranslatef( self.camera_x, self.camera_y, 0 )
        # Scale camera
        glScalef( self.camera_zoom, self.camera_zoom, 1 )

    @camera_matrix
    def zoom_camera(self):
        # Move to camera position
        glTranslatef( self.camera_x, self.camera_y, 0 )
        # Scale camera
        glScalef( self.camera_zoom, self.camera_zoom, 1 )
        # Move back from camera position
        glTranslatef( -self.camera_x, -self.camera_y, 0 )

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, button, modifiers):
        # Move camera
        self.camera_x += dx
        self.camera_y += dy
        self.move_camera()

    def on_mouse_scroll(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        # Get scale factor
        f = ZOOM_IN_FACTOR if dy < 0 else ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR if dy > 0 else 1
        # If zoom_level is in the proper range
        if .2 < self.camera_zoom*f < 5:
            # Zoom camera
            self.camera_x = x
            self.camera_y = y
            self.camera_zoom *= f
            self.zoom_camera()

    def on_draw(self):
        # Clear window with ClearColor
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )

        # Pop default matrix onto current matrix
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )
        glPopMatrix()

        # Save default matrix again
        glPushMatrix()

        # Move to center of the screen
        glTranslatef( self.width/2, self.height/2, 0 )

        # Draw objects
        self.batch.draw()

    def run(self):
        pyglet.app.run()

# Create instance of app and run it
App(500, 500).run()
```

Comment: To me this doesn't look like you're panning, but rather rotating the object around the camera - in _3D_.

Comment: Rotating? I only use `glScale` and `glTranslate`.. anyway, what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After another day of suffering, I finally found a solution: in 2D the easiest way of doing mouse coordinate (pivot point) based zooming and right clicked-and-dragged panning without the jumps is to change the projection matrix with the `glOrtho()` function.

Here is a simplified version of my original code -- if you are using Pyglet with seriuos amount of data, you should consider using Groups and Batches, but for the easier understanding  I used the `glBegin()`, `glColor()`, `glVertex()`, `glEnd()` functions here to draw.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

# Zooming constants
ZOOM_IN_FACTOR = 1.2
ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR = 1/ZOOM_IN_FACTOR

class App(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, width, height, *args, **kwargs):
        conf = Config(sample_buffers=1,
                      samples=4,
                      depth_size=16,
                      double_buffer=True)
        super().__init__(width, height, config=conf, *args, **kwargs)

        #Initialize camera values
        self.left   = 0
        self.right  = width
        self.bottom = 0
        self.top    = height
        self.zoom_level = 1
        self.zoomed_width  = width
        self.zoomed_height = height

    def init_gl(self, width, height):
        # Set clear color
        glClearColor(0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 0/255)

        # Set antialiasing
        glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH )
        glEnable( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH )
        glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST )

        # Set alpha blending
        glEnable( GL_BLEND )
        glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA )

        # Set viewport
        glViewport( 0, 0, width, height )

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        # Set window values
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height
        # Initialize OpenGL context
        self.init_gl(width, height)

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        # Move camera
        self.left   -= dx*self.zoom_level
        self.right  -= dx*self.zoom_level
        self.bottom -= dy*self.zoom_level
        self.top    -= dy*self.zoom_level

    def on_mouse_scroll(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        # Get scale factor
        f = ZOOM_IN_FACTOR if dy > 0 else ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR if dy < 0 else 1
        # If zoom_level is in the proper range
        if .2 < self.zoom_level*f < 5:

            self.zoom_level *= f

            mouse_x = x/self.width
            mouse_y = y/self.height

            mouse_x_in_world = self.left   + mouse_x*self.zoomed_width
            mouse_y_in_world = self.bottom + mouse_y*self.zoomed_height

            self.zoomed_width  *= f
            self.zoomed_height *= f

            self.left   = mouse_x_in_world - mouse_x*self.zoomed_width
            self.right  = mouse_x_in_world + (1 - mouse_x)*self.zoomed_width
            self.bottom = mouse_y_in_world - mouse_y*self.zoomed_height
            self.top    = mouse_y_in_world + (1 - mouse_y)*self.zoomed_height

    def on_draw(self):
        # Initialize Projection matrix
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
        glLoadIdentity()

        # Initialize Modelview matrix
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )
        glLoadIdentity()
        # Save the default modelview matrix
        glPushMatrix()

        # Clear window with ClearColor
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )

        # Set orthographic projection matrix
        glOrtho( self.left, self.right, self.bottom, self.top, 1, -1 )

        # Draw quad
        glBegin( GL_QUADS )
        glColor3ub( 0xFF, 0, 0 )
        glVertex2i( 10, 10 )

        glColor3ub( 0xFF, 0xFF, 0 )
        glVertex2i( 110, 10 )

        glColor3ub( 0, 0xFF, 0 )
        glVertex2i( 110, 110 )

        glColor3ub( 0, 0, 0xFF )
        glVertex2i( 10, 110 )
        glEnd()

        # Remove default modelview matrix
        glPopMatrix()

    def run(self):
        pyglet.app.run()


App(500, 500).run()
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Building on this, I discovered that there is a function called gluOrtho2d specificially designed to set the bounds of your orthographic projection in 2d. It simply takes the l,r,b,t arguments so you don't have to bother with the other 2

Comment: @dusktreader this is a pretty old post -- and actually at that time I only started learning OpenGL. what I recommend you to do is to read the [OpenGL SuperBible 7th edition](http://www.openglsuperbible.com), because we are not using "immediate" more anymore (especially not from Python). Pyglet has support -- though not complete one -- for more modern OpenGL approaches!

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `glTranslatef` don't work absolutely. Instead, they move the "world" by the specified amount. So if you say `glTranslatef(100,100)` you end up 100 units right and down from where you are right now, not at `100, 100`.

What they do in the background is modify the current view matrix. To make this work, you need to write the code like this:

```
glPushMatrix() # save the current matrix somewhere; gives you a new copy to modify

glTranslatef(100,100) # modify your copy; 
                      # you need to do this *every time* before you draw anything
... draw ...

glPopMatrix() # undo all and any change you made to the matrix
```

Comment: I thought that is what my `camera_matrix` decorator does. Before I call `glTranslate` and `glScale` I switch the matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW` and then popping the matrix, load an identical one, do the transformations and push the modified version back.. So what exactly am I doing wrong? (If I change the order to your version, where you push first and then pop -- nothing is happenning: both pan and zoom not working!)

Comment: The first "pop matrix" probably doesn't do anything since there is no matrix to pop. You first need to push a matrix on the stack before you can pop anything. This means in your code, you must **always** first push, then pop, **never** the other way around.

Comment: The first push is happening in the `init_gl` method -- after I initialized the matrices, I push them to the stack, that's why other method calls starts with pop and ends with push. So you are saying that is wrong?

Comment: I have never seen code that does push/pop outside of `on_draw()`. I wouldn't want to bet that the matrix from `init_gl()` is still on the stack when `on_draw()` is being called. From a stability point of view, I'd clear the stack and then call `on_draw()` to make sure simple bugs don't crash the application.

Comment: Well, technically it doesn't matter if it is outside the `on_draw` or not, because `on_draw` is only a method that is poked after any other events were fired -- and since OpenGL is a state-machine, the methods in a Window class are only the *managers* providing that calling glFunctions will be done in the proper order. Anyway, I changed the way you suggested, and it is still jumping and not working as it should..

Comment: What I'm saying is that you have no control over the code outside of `on_draw()`. It might change the matrix stack. That said, you should translate and scale once. In your code, for each redraw, you translate three times and scale twice.

Comment: Now only for your comment's sake, I removed almost everything, calling stuffs inside `on_draw` only and [THIS CODE](http://chopapp.com/#1uzsopnf) still not working -- *you can comment inside the code if you think it is necessary*