# Why is pyglet.app.run() dispatching on_resize() repeatedly leading to max recursion depth error?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, resize, window, pyglet

I am trying to make a simple pyglet app (with Python 3.7) where I can draw a grid, some tiles, color them etc. While also being able to pan, zoom around, so I followed this question :

[How to pan and zoom properly in 2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428258/how-to-pan-and-zoom-properly-in-2d)

However the `on_resize()` event of the `MyWindow` subclass
seems to be called repeatedly after `run()` is called, even if I don't touch the window, and the script crashes with a *max recursion depth*, except when I comment out its `self.width = width` and `self.height = height` lines.
But then resizing the window squishes the objects I'm drawing...

I would like resizing to just show more of the map, keeping the aspect ratio and size of drawn objects.

I have added some `print()` calls to check what happens, but I'm truly at a loss with what's happening here.

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

from algorithm.priorityqueue import PriorityQueue
from algorithm.squaregrid import heuristic, SquareGrid

ZOOM_IN_FACTOR = 1.2
ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR = 1/ZOOM_IN_FACTOR

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [0,0,0, 1000,0,0, 1000,1000,0]),
                                                       ('c4B', self.color*3))

    def draw(self, x, y, z):
        glTranslatef(x, y, z)
        self.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)
        glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z)

class Tile:

    def __init__(self, size, color):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(
                                        4, ('v3f', [0,0,0, 0+self.size,0,0, 
                                        0+self.size,0+self.size,0, 0,0+self.size,0]),
                                        ('c4B', self.color*4))

    def draw(self, x, y, z):
        glTranslatef(x, y, z)
        self.vertices.draw(GL_QUADS)
        glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z)

class Line:

    def __init__(self, start, end, color, stroke):
        self.color = color
        self.stroke = stroke
        self.sx, self.sy = start
        self.ex, self.ey = end

        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(
                                        2, ('v3f', [self.sx,self.sy,0, self.ex,self.ey,0]),
                                        ('c4B', self.color*2))

    def draw(self):
        glLineWidth(self.stroke)
        self.vertices.draw(GL_LINES)


class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, *args, **kwargs):
        conf = Config(sample_buffers=1,
                      samples=4,
                      depth_size=16,
                      double_buffer=True)
        super().__init__(width, height, config=conf, *args, **kwargs)

        #self.set_minimum_size(960, 540)
        #glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)

        #glOrtho(0, self.width, 0, self.height, -10, 10) # setup orthogonal projection

        self.left = 0
        self.right = width
        self.bottom = 0
        self.top = height
        self.zoom_level = 1
        self.zoomed_width = width
        self.zoomed_height = height
        print("init finished")

    def init_gl(self, width, height):
        print("init_gl started")
        # Clear color
        glClearColor(255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 255/255)

        # Antialiasing
        glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
        glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
        glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)

        # Alpha Blending
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

        # Viewport
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


    def drawstuff(self):
        print("drawstuff called")
        self.triangle = Triangle((255, 0, 0, 255))
        self.square = Tile(10, (255,0,255,255))

        self.gridlines = []
        for j in range(0,25):
            self.gridlines.append(Line((0, 40*j),(1000, 40*j),(50,50,50,255), 2))
        for i in range(0,25):
            self.gridlines.append(Line((40*i, 0),(40*i, 1000),(50,50,50,255), 2))       

    def on_resize(self, width, height):

        print("on_resize called")

        # It crashes here!
        self.width = width
        print(width)
        self.height = height
        print(height)

        self.init_gl(width, height)

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        # Move camera
        self.left -= dx*self.zoom_level
        self.right -= dx*self.zoom_level
        self.bottom -= dy*self.zoom_level
        self.top -= dy*self.zoom_level       

    def on_mouse_scroll(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        # Scale factor
        f = ZOOM_IN_FACTOR if dy<0 else ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR if dy>0 else 1
        # If in proper range
        if .2 < self.zoom_level*f < 5:

            self.zoom_level *= f

            print(self.width, self.height)

            mouse_x = x/self.width
            mouse_y = y/self.height

            mouse_x_in_world = self.left + mouse_x * self.zoomed_width
            mouse_y_in_world = self.bottom + mouse_y * self.zoomed_height

            self.zoomed_width *= f
            self.zoomed_height *= f

            self.left = mouse_x_in_world - mouse_x * self.zoomed_width
            self.right = mouse_x_in_world + (1 - mouse_x) * self.zoomed_width
            self.bottom = mouse_y_in_world - mouse_y * self.zoomed_height
            self.top = mouse_y_in_world + (1 - mouse_y) * self.zoomed_height

    def on_draw(self):
        print("draw called")
        # Init projection matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()

        # Init Modelview matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        # Save default modelview matrix
        glPushMatrix()

        # Clear window with ClearColor
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        # Set Orthographic projection matrix
        glOrtho(self.left, self.right, self.bottom, self.top, 1, -1)

        #self.draw_background()
        self.triangle.draw(0, 0, 0)
        self.square.draw(-100, -100, 0)
        for line in self.gridlines:
            line.draw()

        # Remove default modelview matrix
        glPopMatrix()

    def run(self):
        print("run called")
        pyglet.app.run()
        print("run finished")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = MyWindow(800, 500, resizable=True)
    App.drawstuff()
    App.run()
```

And the console shows :

```
$ python3 environments/testapp.py
init finished
drawstuff called
run called
on_resize called
on_resize called
on_resize called
on_resize called
on_resize called
```

etc. with at some point :

```
on_resize called
on_resize called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "environments/testapp.py", line 185, in <module>
    App.run()
  File "environments/testapp.py", line 177, in run
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 107, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 159, in run
    self._legacy_setup()
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 182, in _legacy_setup
    window.dispatch_pending_events()
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 914, in dispatch_pending_events
    EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *self._event_queue.pop(0))
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 415, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "environments/testapp.py", line 110, in on_resize
    self.width = width
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 964, in width
    self.set_size(new_width, self.height)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 574, in set_size
    self.dispatch_event('on_resize', width, height)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1323, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 415, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "environments/testapp.py", line 110, in on_resize
    self.width = width
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 964, in width
    self.set_size(new_width, self.height)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 574, in set_size
    self.dispatch_event('on_resize', width, height)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1323, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
```

With the last 10 lines repeating for a while, and at the end :

```
if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 415, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "environments/testapp.py", line 108, in on_resize
    print("on_resize called")
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I find it weird that `run()` is calling `on_resize()` on its own, and I really have no clue as to why reassigning the attributes self.width and self.height is entering a recursion.

It also crashes when the value assigned is not width or height, but any constant number as well, and also whether the Window instance is passed `resizable = True` or `= False` as argument

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. The application works fine (at least for me)

Comment: *"I find it weird that run() is calling on_resize() on its own"* - `run` does not call `on_resize()`, But run executes the event loop and the resize event occurs once after initializing the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run` does not call `on_resize()`, but run executes the event loop and the resize event occurs once after initializing the window.
[`pyglet.window`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html) provides the properties `.width` and `.height`, thus there is no need to set them by `self.width = width` respectively `self.height = height`. Likely, assigning a value to `self.width` or  `self.height` triggers the `on_resize` event. If you do that in `on_resize`, that causes an endless  recursion.

That `self.width` and `self.height` contain the current size of the window, can be verified with ease, by printing the values in `on_resize`:

```py
class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    # [...]

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        print("on_resize called")
        print(self.width, width)
        print(self.height, height)
```

Do not assign a value to `self.width` or `self.height`, if the new value is equal the current value:

```py
class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    # [...]

    def on_resize(self, width, height):

        new_width = ...
        new_height = ...

        if new_width != width:
            self.width = new_width
        if new_height != height:
            self.height = new_height
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand how Window assigns their values to width and height now, I should have looked into it a little more!

Also, how would you go about allowing the window to be resized without modifying the objects' shape or size? on_resize has to change some values but I cannot seem to find which.